# Javascript parse binary file

Tags: javascript, php, file, binary

I'm trying to transfer a binary file from server (PHP) to client. Then I need to parse binary file in javascript so I can plot values using a chart.

To parse binary file I'm using JParser library. When I try to read a negative int16 value result is wrong. Here some code:

**AJAX POST**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getComtrade.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { getDat: "filename.dat" },
    success: function(data){
        handleDatFile(data);
        console.log(parser.parse('header'));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
);
```

**JPARSER STRUCT**

```
function handleDatFile(data){
    var view = new jDataView(data, undefined, undefined, true);

    parser = new jParser(view, {
        header: {
            ID: 'uint32',
            sample: 'uint32',
            analogs: ['array', 'int16', 8],
            digitals: ['array', 4, 29]
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
public static function getFileDat($fileName)
{
    $filepath = COMTRADE_DIR . "/" . $fileName;

    echo file_get_contents($filepath);
}
```

In particular, hex value 'F52E' is parsed in '-722'. Correct value is '-2770'.

Thank you.